# Does magento version belongs to question title?

Tags: discussion

**Where does Magento version belongs to?**

- to the questions title
- to the questions tag

During last days i've seen a lot of edit where `Magento 2:` was put in front of the question. In my opinion, this isn't the correct way ... it should be enough to set appropriate tag and keep the title as it is.

And ... should these title be "fixed" again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When M2 started and people in here were not used to it, there was a common practice to add `Magento 2` in the title of the question.
Now it does not make sense to do so.
But please don go on an edit rampage to remove "magento 2" from the titles.
Just don't approve these edits if you see any.

Answer (score 3):

everyone is not aware about the tags , new users always add tags randomly and from their description,

its hard to tell for which version they are asking , because many times they don't include code,

so if they have mentioned some where that they asking for M2 then I think its okay for new users